# Perl multiline pattern match using grep

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my script to check if copyright exists in a file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'first';

my $filename="sample.txt"; # this file name will be passed-in to the script.
my @fileContent=`cat $filename`;
my $copyrightFound = first { /copyright .* Shakespeare/i } @fileContent;
if (!$copyrightFound) {
   print "\nERROR: Copyright missing\n";
   exit;
}
#copyright Found
print @fileContent;
if (grep /Copyright (c) \d+ by Bill Shakespeare\nAll rights reserved./,@fileContent ) {
  print "\nCopyright is good\n";
} else {
  print "\nCopyright needs to be fixed\n";
}
```

prints:

```
$ perl copyrightCheck.pl 
Copyright (c) 2010 by Bill Shakespeare
All rights reserved.


Copyright needs to be fixed
```

but the copyright is good, is there a better way to check this? or whats wrong with my grep command? also `All rights reserved.` can appear in the same line or next line, can I use `\n*` to check the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you loaded the file into an array of file's lines, so `Copyright (c) 2010 by Bill Shakespeare` and `All rights reserved.` end up in separate array elements. You then try to match your multi-line copyright string on the elements of this array, which fails.

To fix this, you can try loading the file into a scalar and use regex match on that scalar. You also need to escape any parentheses that you want to match:

```
my $fileContent = `cat $filename`;
...
if ($fileContent =~ /Copyright \(c\) \d+ by Bill Shakespeare\nAll rights reserved./)
{
    ...
}
```

I would also advice you to use Perl's `open` function and `<>` operator to load the contents of a file to a variable.